# Applying user-specified datetime settings across in an MVC model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datetime, model, data-annotations

I have a user object that is instantiated when a user logs in, this object stores all the user's settings:

```
public class SiteUser
{

    public string LoginId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public DateTime PasswordChangedOn { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string DateFormat { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }        
    public ICollection<SitePermission> SitePermissions { get; set; }
}
```

And a UserContext class that stores and manages the user's session

```
   public class UserContext
   {
         public SiteUser SiteUser { get; internal set; }

         public static UserContext Current
         {
                get
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
                        return null;

                    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserContext"] == null)
                        CreateUserContext();

                    return (UserContext)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserContext"];
                }
            }
    }
```

Now, whenever I have to display a date, be it in a grid, or in a text field, I would always want to reference the `DateFormat` property of the SiteUser object.

In most of the examples I see, data annotations are used to define the format of the date as such:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime PasswordChangedOn { get; set; }
```

I have tried modifying it to this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = UserContext.Current.SiteUser.DateFormat, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

But it didn't work, giving me an error stating that the attribute argument must be a constant.

So what's the best approach to set the format of my date to my models in an MVC application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property in your view model and use that to render the date rather which would take into account the user specific date and render that in the view instead e.g.

```
public string PasswordChangedOnLocal
{
    get { return PasswordChangedOn.ToString(DateFormat); }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just render the date in the view itself using the `DateFormat` property. This actually gives you a bit more flexibility if wanted to change it later (e.g. went for a system-wide convention) as you wouldn't need to recompile the site e.g.

```
@model SiteUser

...
<div id="passwordChangedOn">@Model.PasswordChangedOn.ToString(Model.DateFormat)</div>
...
```

Comment: So, I would need a 2nd property in my models for all my datetime properties? E.g., if i have 50 datetime properties across 20 different models, I will have to add a "OnLocal" variant for each of them?

Comment: I know your solution will do the job, but is there a more unified way in doing so? I actually like MVC's way of styling the dates, the only downside to that is.. the format must be hardcoded

Comment: @ParityBit Your issue with 50 datetime properties is going to serve you the same problem regardless of what way you go about it as all these dates need to be manually formatted. The 20 different models is easily solved by introducing a base class. If you have multiple property fields then I think doing it directly in the view may be the best option.

Comment: @ParityBit Another alternative, if you aren't against using a 3rd party lib, is [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). You can apply custom formatters to specific types etc.